# Contact Builder - Populations and Attribute Groups

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

The Populations thing still confuses me at times. Here's the model we need.

We have a data extension GlobalContacts. The client will be adding records through the API. This data extension is set-up in an Attribute Group relating to (ContactBuilder) Contact by Subscriber Key. There is a second table that relates to GlobalContacts called Party.

We will use a filtered data extension from GlobalContact as an Entry Data Extension for Journey Builder. So my understanding is for those contacts to be injected they need to exist in a Population.

Here's where I'm confused...I think GlobalContacts should be the Population, but then I can't add it in an Attribute Group to relate to Contact and the Party Data Extension.

What am I missing? Am I going down the wrong path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going down the right path Victor - Populations are replacing the "Root" functionality in data extensions (which essentially translates to: A subscriber can appear here, before it is added to the all subscriber list) - simplistically put :)

Based on your outline, I agree - GlobalContacts should be a population.

What will happen is that the GlobalContacts will be "identical" in a way to All Subscribers.

What this implies is that it goes across the entire contact builder data model. Thus, when you are trying to link the Party Data Extension to the all subscribers, you will have a new "menu point" on the left side of the link. Essentially:

- Left side of "link data extension" shows all subscribers
- Scroll down to the bottom, and you will see the data extensions you have marked as populations
- Click the name of the DE and you can now choose the relevant field here (which represents the link to All Subscribers)
- on the right, click the field as your normally would

Hope this helps to clarify?

Comment: Hey Kenneth, Thank you for your response. I think this is what I need, but I'm a little lost in finding the "menu point"...Is this in Contact Builder?

Comment: I found it. Although, I think our data model won't work that way. The GlobalContact to Party is a Many to 1. Having the GlobalContact on the left doesn't allow me to set the cardinality for GlobalContact. I think I may need to create a sub-set of GlobalContact to use as a Population.

Comment: Interesting.. that sounds like a bug / area of improvement - Will investigate

Comment: I've tested in my account, and overall, after adding the population i can go back to the attribute groups and link a DE to the population where i do have the cardinality selectore - one or many. Can you share more information about you DE's? It might require a support ticket in case it doesn't work.

Comment: Hmmm...so in the Population GlobalContacts (PartyID) is not a Primary Key. It is a PK on the Party table. I can set GlobalContacts as a 1 to many to Party (1 GlobalContact to many Party, but it's actually the other way many GlobalContacts to 1 Party???